# How to read and update document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to read a document, Get the data and update it.

Example

```
{
  _id : "001",
  fetch : 50,
  field : 0,
}
```

```
 data = DB.Collection.findOne({_id:"001"})

 DB.Collection.updateOne({_id:"001"}, { $set : { field : data.fetch + 100 } } )
```

How to do same operation with single read & update for atomic operation?

Is there any option like...

```
DB.Collection.updateOne(
  { _id: "001" },
  { $set: { $inc: { "$[element]": 100 } } },
  { $get: { element: "field" } } // something like this?
)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `findOneAndUpdate` and `findAndModify` update operations.

Comment: #prasad_.Can I read data from `findOneAndUpdate` or `findAndModify ` and update it base on the data ? Can you gave me any example ?

Comment: There is detailed description explaining the command's behavior _and_ examples in the documentation. Please feel free to type in the command name in the Google (or your favorite search software's) search box.

Comment: No offense,But thanks for your advice and I looked at the documentation. Maybe I hardly understand something wrong. That's why I asked for an example.You can see that in the example, I have set `field` with `data.fetch + 100`. And  how can I get the  `data.fetch` ?

Comment: I think you can try using the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html) instead of `$set`.

Comment: No.This is just an example. I am trying get the data and base on the return data update it...I have edit my question for better understanding ...

Comment: Then you need to use [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html). This allows you to use the update operation using the field(s) of the document being updated.